# Where is the .CSS in ASP.NET for specific views? - Visual Studio 2014

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have created an ASP.NET application. I want to change color, position etcetera in the .CSS-file for a specific View.

The only .CSS-files I can find are the ones in the Content-Folder (Bootstrap, Bootstrap.min and Site).

And the Site.CSS hardly contains anything at all.

I was doing a tutorial where you changed it through the Page Inspector and if you had the Page Inspector Version 1.3 the changes in the Page Inspector were auto-committed. It did not work for me.

Therfore, my question is:

**If I want to change things in the .CSS for a specific view where do I do that?**
Let's say for example in the default(generated automatically) ASP.NET Folder "Views - Home - Contact" 
I would like to change the backgroundcolor *in this view only* to grey. How do I do that?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: The feature where you change it in the page inspector of the browser and it updates your CSS files is called [Browser Link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link).

Comment: Then you need to create CSS that applies to only that view. A usually is part of a layout so you would need to create a specific CSS for that layout, over-ride the specific CSS attributes for that view. You normally don't create CSS for views separately though.

Comment: When you state: "You normally don't create CSS for views separately though." How do you normally do it then? Make the changes in the Site.css so the changes apply to all views?

Comment: @Chris89 No, you can use [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (classes, ID's, element names etc) to apply different styles.